# Equivalence of cryptographic problems

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, factoring

Are integer factorization, discrete log and ECDH problems equivalent?

I know that factorization and discrete log are equivalent but are one of those two problem equivalent with ECDH? Cand someone provide some references? Thank you!

Comment: RSA has [RSA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem): Just as there are no proofs that integer factorization is computationally difficult, there are also no proofs that the RSA problem is similarly difficult.

Comment: Yes, but if one can determine n1n2P from n1P and n2P, where n1,n2 are integers and P is a point on elliptic curve, it is possible to use that algorithm in order to factorize some integer?

Comment: Contrary to the question's assertion, factorization (of composite $n$) and Discrete Log (in $\Bbb Z_p^*$ for prime $p$) are _not_ known to be equivalent. Obviously, ECDH is no harder than Discrete Log in that EC group.

Comment: I guess OP was thinking about the implication "factoring is hard -> discrete log is hard over the cyclic subgroups of Zn" (which, btw, is only in one direction).

Comment: I see. Since they are all breakable with Shor's algorithm I presumed that they are equivalent

Comment: Being equivalent is usually meant as: there is a classical randomized polynomial time reduction from breaking A to breaking B, and conversely. Both being broken by Shor's algorithm simply make them equivalent (and in fact, insecure) in the quantum world, but says nothing about the equivalence in the classical world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be clear with how you define "discrete log" here, since it depends on the underlying group. The generic discrete logarithm assumption states (somewhat informally) "there exists a group over which the discrete logarithm cannot be solved in polynomial time".

The ECDH problem, on the other hand, refers to the Diffie-Hellman problem over "some" elliptic curve. Depending on the context, you can either see that as a concrete assumption ("DDH/CDH is hard over *this* specific curve") or as a more general one ("there exists (a family of) elliptic curves such that DDH/CDH is hard over these curves").

Eventually, factorization simply states that given a random sample from some appropriate distribution over the integers, it should be infeasible to recover the factors in polynomial time. Typically, we will consider the distribution obtained by multiplying two random primes of the same size, but other distributions can be - and are often - considered.

That being said, not much is known about the equivalences between assumptions that do not share a similar structure in general. In particular:

- Discrete logarithm clearly implies the existence of a group in which both CDH and DDH are hard
- However, only ECDL (the existence of an elliptic curve over which the discrete log is hard) is known to imply ECDH (put otherwise: we have no reduction of the form "if there is a group where dlog is hard, then there is an elliptic curve where dlog is hard")
- If the discrete logarithm is easy over the multiplicative subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, where $n$ is a product of two large primes, then $n$ can be factored efficiently. In fact, it suffices that the computational Diffie-Hellman assumption is easy over one of these subgroups for factoring to become easy. Here is the proof: fix a subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (e.g. the group of quadratic residues). Given a random $x \in G$, set $g \gets x^2$, and run the CDH solver on $(x^2,x,x)$ to get $x^{1/2}$ (I assume for simplicity that the solver always work - the proof can be extended to the case where the solver only works with good probability on random CDH instances). This works since $x = (x^2)^{1/2}$, hence $CDH(x^2, x, x) = (x^2)^{(1/2)\cdot (1/2)} = x^{1/2}$. Since the ability to compute square roots in subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ implies the existence of an efficient factoring algorithm (this is an easy proof, left as an exercise), the conclusion follows.